# How to call a Oracle database sequence number by using MyBatis?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I want to call a sequence number from my Oracle Database 10g by using MyBatis, but I only get an error message like the following:

```
ORA-02289: Sequence is not available.
```

How can I call a sequence number from an Oracle Database?

Here is my Maven Project Dependency concerning the current MyBatis Version:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
   <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my Dao Java class:

```
long mySeqNumber = myDaoClass.getNewNumber(); // here I get an exception
```

Here is my xml declaration:

```
<select id="getNewNumber" resultType="java.lang.Long" >
    SELECT mySeq.nextval
    FROM dual
</select>
```

Comment: and presumably running the select from the sequence works perfectly when logged in to the database as the same user that Java is logged in as?

Comment: `SELECT mySeq.nextval
    FROM dual` change to `SELECT nextVal('mySeq')`

Comment: @Afsun Khammadli: With your solution I get the error ORA-00904: "NEXTVAL": invalid identifier

Comment: For what you will use sequence nextval?I think you will use for inserting isn't it?

Comment: Yes for an SQL Insert, but first I need to get the next Sequence number and than I put the sequence number into a XML Insert Statement as parameter

Comment: `<insert id="insertMyObject" parameterType="MyObject" useGeneratedKeys="true">
 
        <selectKey keyProperty="objectId" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
            SELECT nextVal('my_sequence')
            <!-- or ->  SELECT my_sequence.nextVal from dual   -->
        </selectKey>
 
        INSERT INTO myobject_table (objectId,objectName)
            VALUES (#{objectId},#{objectName})
 
    </insert>` Please check this.

Comment: maybe try adding a public synonym, or specify schema/owner (select SOMESCHEMA.SOMESEQ.nextval ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use nextval for inserting.Try following:

```
<insert id="insertPerson" parameterType="Person" useGeneratedKeys="true"> 
  <selectKey keyProperty="personId" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
    SELECT nextVal('mySeq')
  </selectKey>
  INSERT INTO person (personId,PersonName) VALUES (#{personId},#{personName}) 
</insert>
```

Also instead of `SELECT nextVal('mySeq')` you can use this `SELECT mySeq.nextVal from dual`

Comment: Now I get this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for myClass

Comment: You must change parameters for your table structure.

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea, what muste be changed here: <insert id="insertLog" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" useGeneratedKeys="true"> <selectKey keyProperty="myId" resultType="long" order="BEFORE"> SELECT nextVal('mySeq') </selectKey> INSERT INTO ${mySchema}.myTable ( id, loggingtime) VALUES( #{myId}, sysdate) </insert>

Comment: I think my answer is true.There is any problem may be in your code.Please change `sysdate` to `sysdate()`

Comment: No sysdate is not the problem. The problem ist anywhere else in my sourcecode, but I can´t find the mistake

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency> 



<select id="getUploadId" resultType="int">
    select {schema}.SEQUENCE_NAME.NEXTVAL from dual
</select>
```